# The "A*" algorithm interferes with the enemy script that would knockback and I don't know what to change

Tags: function, game-maker-studio-2

I'm trying to add the "A*" in the enemy script to improve movement,
here is the function:

```
function scr_slime_perseguindo(){
    image_speed=1.5;
    
    dest_x=obj_player.x;
    dest_y=obj_player.y;
    
    if(mp_grid_path(obj_map.mp_grid,caminho,x,y,dest_x,dest_y,true)){
    path_start(caminho,veloc_perseg,path_action_stop,false);
    }
    
    scr_slime_colisao();
    
    if distance_to_object(obj_player)>=dist_desaggro{
        estado=scr_slime_escolher_estado;
        alarm[0]=irandom_range(120,240);
    }
    
}
```

the original function was this:

```
function scr_slime_perseguindo(){
    image_speed=1.5;
    
    dest_x=obj_player.x;
    dest_y=obj_player.y;
    
    var _dir=point_direction(x,y,dest_x,dest_y);
    hveloc=lengthdir_x(veloc_perseg,_dir);
    vveloc=lengthdir_y(veloc_perseg,_dir);
    
    scr_slime_colisao();
    
    if distance_to_object(obj_player)>=dist_desaggro{
        estado=scr_slime_escolher_estado;
        alarm[0]=irandom_range(120,240);
    }
    
}
```

but when attacking the enemy would receive a knockback with this function

```
function scr_slime_hit(){
    alarm[2]=180;
    empurrar_veloc=lerp(empurrar_veloc,0,0.05);
    
    hveloc=lengthdir_x(empurrar_veloc,empurrar_dir);
    vveloc=lengthdir_y(empurrar_veloc,empurrar_dir);

    scr_slime_colisao();
}
```

stop working.

I would like to know if there is a way to fix this or if I would have to rewrite all two functions to work together,
if I leave any information out, please let me know so I can clarify more, thx!